# Information leakage in Cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

#### Description of classification problem:

- Assume a regular dataset `X` with `n` samples and `d` features.
- This classification problem is somewhat hard (many features, few samples, low overall AUC `~70%`).
- It might be useful to mention that feature selection/extraction, dimension reduction, kernels, many classifiers have been applied. So I am not interested in trying these.
- I am not looking forward to see an improvement in overall AUC. The goal is to find relevant features in haystack of features.

#### Description of my approach:

1. I select all pairwise combination of `d` features and create many two dimensional sub-datasets `x` with `n` samples.
2. On each sub-dataset `x`, I perform a 10-fold cross-validation (using all samples of the main dataset `X`). A very long process, assume weeks of computation.
3. I select top `k` pairs (according to highest AUC for example) and label them as `+`. All other pairs are labeled as `-`.
4. For each pair, I can compute several properties (e.g. relations between each pair using Expert's knowledge). These properties can be calculated without using the labels in main dataset `X`.
5. Now I have pairs which are labeled as `+` or `-`. In addition, each pair has many properties calculated based on Expert's knowledge (i.e. features). Hence, I have a new classification problem. Lets call this newly generated dataset `Y`.
6. I train a classifier on `Y` while following cross-validation rules. Surprisingly, I can predict the `+` and `-` labels with `90%` AUC.

As far as I can see, it means that I am able to select relevant features. However, seeing a `90%` AUC makes me worried about information leakage somewhere in this long process. Specially in step 3.
I was wondering if anyone can see any leakage in this approach.

---

Information Leakage:

- Incorporation of target labels in the actual features. Your classifier will produce good prediction while did not learn anything.
- Showing your test set to you classifier during the training phase. Your classifier will "memorize" the test set and its corresponding labels without "learning" anything.

#### Update 1:

I want to stress that indeed I am using all data points of `X` in step 1. However, I am not using them ever again (even for testing). The final 90% AUC is obtained from predicting labels of dataset `Y`.
On the other hand, it would be useful to note that, even if I randomize the values of my main dataset `X`, the computed features for dataset `Y` is going to be the same. However, the sample labels in `Y` would change because the previous `+` pairs might not be a good one anymore. Therefore they will be labeled as `-`.

#### Update 2:

Although I haven't got any opinion, I am going to state what I have got during 4 days of talking with pattern recognition researchers. Briefly I became confident that there is no information leakage (as long as I wont go back to the first dataset `X` and using its labels). Later on, in case I wanted to check to see if I could have better performance in `X` (i.e. predicting sample labels), I need to use only a part of dataset `X` for pairwise comparison (as training set). Then I can use the rest of samples in `X` as test set while using positively predicted pairs of `Y` as features.
I will set this as an answer in case no one could reject this method.

Answer (score 0):

If your processes in step 1 uses all data. then the features you are learning have information from the whole data set. Since you selected based on the whole dataset and THEN validation, you are leaking serious information.

You should probably stick with tools that are well known / already done for you before running out and trying weird strategies like this. Try using a model with L1 regularization to do feature selection for your, or start with some of the simpler searches like Sequential Backward Selection.

If you do cross validation correctly in the end, each training will perform its own independent feature selection. If you do one global feature selection and then do CV, you are going to be doing it wrong and probably leaking information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Raff. I guess you misread what I wrote. If you look at step 6, I mentioned that I am getting 90% AUC on NEWLY created dataset. In addition, I also stated that nearly all feature selection/extraction methods have been applied. Including L1 regularization (which is called Lasso). I will add some updates to avoid future confusion.